# JSON parsing to multiple POJOs collection

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

I need to somehow convert a single json string into multiple objects of a particular type using GSON.

I have the format of a single json string (below contains 2 but there may be 100s)

```
{domain : name1, geo: us} {domain : name2, country : uk}
```

Now I want to convert the above into my pojo instances that map to each part of the string. Suppose the POJO is called Website. Then I need to split up the json string to 2 Website objects.

I was thinking of splitting the json string using a tokenizer of some sort and then applying some json logic on each part. I'm assuming I would have to do this before applying any json to pojo conversion?

I cant seem to find a way to do this. Please advise.

thanks so much

Comment: That's not JSON for two reasons:  the keys and strings need quoting; the two JSON objects need to be in an array i.e. `[ { ... }, { ... } ]`

Comment: yes unfortunately stuck with gson. Although if there are alternatives I can always try convincing.

Comment: yes unfortunately stuck with gson. Although if there are alternatives I can always try convincing. @JeremyP each entry will be returned as a separate json object, not as an array to the browser for display. And you are correct, they will have quotes, I just left them out sorry about that. Any tips on how to progress then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deserialize json to a java pojo, try json-lib, http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/.  This is a good solution.  Although I would use flexjson for serialization.

```
String json = "{bool:true,integer:1,string:\"json\"}";  
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject( json );  
BeanA bean = (BeanA) JSONObject.toBean( jsonObject, BeanA.class );
```

where BeanA is your POJO.

If you have muliple objects, like you showed in your example then do the following

```
String json = "{'data':[{'name':'Wallace'},{'name':'Grommit'}]}";
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(json);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
   BeanA bean = (BeanA) JSONObject.toBean( jsonObject, BeanA.class );
   //do whatever you want with each object
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a class Website like this:

```
class Website {
    String domain;
    String geo;
}
```

First fix your string to be valid json:

```
String input = "{\"domain\" : \"name1\", \"geo\": \"us\"} {\"domain\" : \"name2\", \"country\" : \"uk\"}";

String json = "[" + input + "]";
```

Then use standard gson technique to convert to List of Website:

```
java.lang.reflect.Type t = new TypeToken<List<Website>>(){}.getType();
List<Website> websites = new Gson().fromJson(json, t);
```